# Extracting values from array of objects

Tags: javascript

I have an array that looks like this one:

```
[
    {
        "users": [
            {
               "name": "John",
               "location": "USA",
                "age": "34",
            },
           {
                "name": "John",
               "location": "California",
                "address": "Silk Road 123"
            },
           {
               "name": "Jane",
               "last-name": "Edmus"
               "location": "USA"
            }
        ]
    },

]
```

I want to merge the objects whose name match. I found this helper function:

```
 findByMatchingProperties = (set, properties) => {
  return set.filter(function (entry) {
      return Object.keys(properties).every(function (key) {
          return console.log(entry[key] === properties[key]);
      });
  });
}
```

But it is not budging. Any ideas on how I could go about this? The expected outcome should be:

```
 [ { "users": [ { "name": "John", "location": ["USA", "California"}, "age": "34", "address": "Silk Road 123" }, { "name": "Jane", "last-name": "Edmus" "location": "USA" } ] }, ]
```

Comment: What is that helper function even supposed to do? It does `filter` so it would be removing some of the elements, but the callback then does `console.log(entry[key] === properties[key])` which will *print* the result of the equality but `console.log()` always returns `undefined`, so the result is always falsey.

Comment: What is expected output ?

Comment: The expected output would be: [
  {
      "users": [
          {
             "name": "John",
             "location": ["USA", "California"},
              "age": "34",
              "address": "Silk Road 123"
          },
         {
             "name": "Jane",
             "last-name": "Edmus"
             "location": "USA"
          }
      ]
  },

]

Comment: If the answer resolved your issue, please [mark it as accepted](https://stackoverflow.com/help/accepted-answer)

Answer (score 0):

You can achive this by using **[Map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map)** object for optimization and then converting it back to array. Check out code below.

```js
const users = [
  { "name": "John", "location": "USA", "age": "34" },
  { "name": "John", "location": "California", "address": "Silk Road 123" },
  { "name": "John", "location": "Foo", "bar": "baz" },
  { "name": "Jane", "last-name": "Edmus", "location": "USA" }
];

const mergeObjectsExceptProps = (exceptProps, o1, o2) => 
  Object.entries(o2).reduce((acc, [ k, v ]) => {
    if (exceptProps.includes(k)) {
      return acc
    }
    
    let propValueToSet
    if (acc.hasOwnProperty(k)) {
      propValueToSet = [ 
        ...(Array.isArray(acc[k]) ? acc[k] : [ acc[k] ]),
        v
      ]
    } else {
      propValueToSet = v
    }
    
    return {
      ...acc,
      [k]: propValueToSet,
    }
  }, o1)

const usersMap = new Map()

for (const user of users) {
  const foundUser = usersMap.get(user.name)
  
  if (foundUser) {
    usersMap.set(user.name, mergeObjectsExceptProps([ 'name' ], foundUser, user))
  } else {
    usersMap.set(user.name, user)
  }
}

const result = [ ...usersMap.values() ]

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You could [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce) the `users` array and group them based on the `name`. Destructure each user and get the `name` and `rest` of the properties separately. Loop through the keys of `rest` and check if the key already exists in the nested value. If it exists, create an array of values. Else, just add the value:

```js
const input = [{users:[{name:"John",location:"USA",age:"34"},{name:"John",location:"California",address:"Silk Road 123"},{name:"Jane","last-name":"Edmus",location:"USA"}]}];

const merged = input[0].users.reduce((acc, o) => {
  const { name, ...rest } = o;
  const group = acc[name];
  
  // check if name already exists in the accumulator
  if(group) {
    Object.keys(rest).forEach(key => {
      if(key in group)
        group[key] = [].concat(group[key], o[key])
      else
        group[key] = o[key];
    })
  }
  else
    acc[name] = o;
  
  return acc;
},{})

const users = Object.values(merged)

console.log([{ users }])
```

This is what the `merged` object looks like:

```
{
  "John": {
    "name": "John",
    "location": ["USA", "California"],
    "age": "34",
    "address": "Silk Road 123"
  },
  "Jane": {
    ...
  }
}
```

Use [`Object.values()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_objects/Object/values) to get the values of this object to an array